# Is it safe to call loadData() of WebView in the UI thread?

Tags: android, android-webview

A simple example:

```
webview.loadData("http://example.com/html_with_image.php","text/html",null);
```

The loaded page looks like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="lena.jpg" width="768" height="1024">
  </body>
</html>
```

Since transferring the image may take some time I was wondering if `loadData()`has to be threaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebView is loading async anyway, so you shoudnt worry about that.

Comment: I was not sure if this is the case but I believe you ;-)

Comment: You have a link that explain that?